# Gerar Length Separado para cada objeto

Tags: javascript

Olá, tudo certo ?

Como eu faço para gerar um numero correspondente para cada Objeto, exemplo

```
{
    "api": "api",
    "List": [{
        "tipo": "1",
        "data": "10/10/2017",
        "Hora": "11:38",
        "Size": "0",
        "Nome": "Marcelo"
    }, {
        "tipo": "1",
        "data": "10/10/2017",
        "Hora": "11:38",
        "Size": "0",
        "Nome": "Pedro"
    }, {
        "tipo": "1",
        "data": "10/10/2017",
        "Hora": "11:38",
        "Size": "0",
        "Nome": "Lucas"
    }],
    "arq": "1",
    "paste": "2"
}
```

Quero gerar um numero para cada nome quando o forEach passar.
Exemplo:
Marcelo > 0
Pedro > 1
Lucas > 2

Toda vez que o forEach passar eu quero que o numero seja correspondente a ordem, por exemplo, se o marcelo ficar em ultimo ele vai ser 2 , e se o Lucas ficar em primeiro ele vai ser o 0

Mais ou menos assim:

```
B=0; B< obj.List.length ; B++
```

Comment: O `.forEach` já te dá isso. Chama-se o indice da array e é o segundo argumento do método. Onde queres usar isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assim como o @Sergio já disse o [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) já suporta o índice, ou seja a posição de cada elemento no array.

Os parâmetros possíveis para o `forEach` são:

```
(valorCorrente, indice, array)
```

Aplicando no seu código ficaria assim:

```js
const json = `{
    "api": "api",
    "List": [{
        "tipo": "1",
        "data": "10/10/2017",
        "Hora": "11:38",
        "Size": "0",
        "Nome": "Marcelo"
    }, {
        "tipo": "1",
        "data": "10/10/2017",
        "Hora": "11:38",
        "Size": "0",
        "Nome": "Pedro"
    }, {
        "tipo": "1",
        "data": "10/10/2017",
        "Hora": "11:38",
        "Size": "0",
        "Nome": "Lucas"
    }],
    "arq": "1",
    "paste": "2"
}`;

let objeto = JSON.parse(json);

objeto.List.forEach((valorCorrente, indice) => { //forEach com valor e indice

  //aqui dentro do forEach cria o numero em cada valor da lista. 
  //Chamei o campo de numero, mas pode ter o nome que quiser
  valorCorrente.numero = indice; 
});

console.log(objeto.List);
```